# Python interprocess communication

Tags: python, rpc

I have a Python application (with GUI, using PyQt4) that gets spawned by the user in several instances. The application is used to execute some long running tasks (about some hours to a few days), so I'm willing to add an extra "monitoring" application that will do things like:

- find all the running processes of the other application
- get the status of the running operations (jobs done, percentage, error messages, ...)
- eventually send some commands to the applications telling them to pause, resume, stop, ...

One way that would fit the job is [RPyC](http://rpyc.wikispaces.com/), the only problem, it seems to work only over TCP sockets, like most of the RPC libraries I found. But this leads to having to open several unneeded sockets listening only on localhost, and having to create some kind of ports allocation mechanism to avoid two processes trying to listen on the same port. And then the monitor needs a list of ports to be written somewhere, or to go and find processes listening on TCP ports and try to figure out whether they are instances of the correct application or ot. Sounds like a mess.

The nicest way of managing the intercommunication I could think of at the moment would be having some unix sockets, let's say, in '/var/run/myapp/myapp-.sock', and then creating a module that does all the dirty stuff exposing some methods like `listMyApps()` and `getMyApp(pid)` returning the first a list of pids, the second an object that could be used for communication with that app.

Now, I'm looking at the best way to accomplish that..
For real, there isn't anything out there already done to manage RPC over unix sockets? Sounds a bit strange to me, but I wasn't able to find anything that could fit..

Any suggestions?

**NOTE:** I don't want to reverse things (applications are client of a single monitoring server) to avoid problems in case of monitoring application crash, and to letting me free to create other  applications that connect to these sockets and make requests.

**NOTE:** Security is not an issue since all this stuff is running in a private, closed and firewalled network :), plus, requests are done on localhost by trusted users only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess I found a soultion by using [dbus-python](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/). I was able to integrate it with the Qt4 mainloop, although on the website they say only glib was supported (I guess that page is not updated). I just did a qick test and it seems to be working nicely (I just esposed some dummy functions on a bus named `com.example.myapp.<pid>` and listed instances and connected from an external client).

Then, I could use the RPyC stuff over TCP only for the communication between a "master" control application and the "manager" application that acts quite like a "switch" between instances on a machine.

Some ascii-art clarification:

```
+-------------------+                    
| MASTER APP        |                    +--------------------+
| on my workstation |------ RPyC --------| Server#0 Manager   |
+-------------------+                    +--------------------+
      |                                      | | |
    RPyC                                     | | '-- dbus ---[INSTANCE #0]
      |                                      | '--- dbus ---[INSTANCE #1]
   +--------------------+                    '---- dbus ---[INSTANCE #2]
   | Server#1 Manager   |
   +--------------------+
      | | |
      | | '-- dbus ---[INSTANCE #0]
      | '--- dbus ---[INSTANCE #1]
      '---- dbus ---[INSTANCE #2]
```

If anyone is interested, just let me know and I'll post some code examples/more details too..

Comment: BTW, the monospace font used by S.O. isn't monospace at all, or it's just me? ASCII-art looks ugly.. :(

Comment: I am having exactly the same dilemma now - multiple, long-running processes spawned independently that are in need of occasional user control (stop, start, etc). This answer was written back in '11. Would you still recommend the dbus solution?

Answer (score 2):

> But this leads to having to open
>   several unneeded sockets listening
>   only on localhost, and having to
>   create some kind of ports allocation
>   mechanism to avoid two processes
>   trying to listen on the same port

Not quite. First, that's how most interprocess communication works, through sockets. Either TCP sockets or UNIX sockets. That's essentially (not exactly) what you're doing when piping standard out and such.

You could also use OS signals. Although you have to keep in mind that only the main thread of each process can do signal handling, so you have to be careful to not block that.

But any way you do it there's pretty much no getting around using socket connections.

Comment: What I meant is, I don't want to setup a listening socket on a different port for each process.. I thought of signals, but they're definitely not enough to do what I need to, since I'd need to run methods on various app functions in order to query its status (not only completion percentage, but much more complex details) or perform a bunch of operations "as if the user clicked the XYZ ui button"..

Answer (score 2):

Another way to go is to have some sort of job control system, and instead of having the application start its own processes, have it register jobs to be started that do the task.  Then the job control system would be monitoring the jobs that are started.  As a bonus, with this design you can spread work out across many machines at some point in the future.

Comment: Yes, this is a good answer. Take a look at python's multiprocessing library.

Comment: What do you suggest for the "job control system"? An older version of the application just spawned several threads of the main app (easy to handle with Python), and where able to communicate with them, but I abandoned that way since having separate processes is more handy if something goes wrong (operations that fail badly or get stuck, bugs in the application itself, ..) and in some cases even to pause/resume process with STOP/CONT..

Comment: You should take a look at the multiprocessing library. There's some good examples there that can direct you.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize there was a library actually called `multiprocessing`, among the never-tried python standard modules.. :)
It seems to be nice, although at a first look it seems like it would need too much refactoring in order to integrate it into my existing application.. That's why I tought of RPC-on-unix-socket..